# Signtool changes file size and corrupts file

Tags: code-signing, signtool

I've gotten a signing certificate for my company. We are trying to sign our  installer.

We use signtool:

```
signtool sign /f %certfile% /p %certpass% /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode file.exe
```

The output exe file is larger than the original.

When you try to run the installer file, you get an error dialog that says "could not initialize installation (CRC)"

Does anyone have any experience with resolving these types of issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this issue was with some built in error checking done by the Wise Installer. The solution was to setup Wise with the PFX file details. The version we have (8.1) doesn't actually sign the files. We still needed to use signtool for that. But if we setup Wise to think it was going to sign the files, the CRC check didn't fail after signing.

Comment: I am faced with the task of codesigning an application packaged with Wise Installation System version 9.02, on a Windows XP system.
My searching has yet to locate Signtool.exe that will run on Windows XP.
But I am interested in the way that you set up Wise with the PFX details which resulted in the correct CRC being generated in The Wise build....

Comment: Have you considered moving the signing operation to another machine? We generate the installer on our build machine. But we do the signing on a separate machine altogether. That may help your issue